# Is "Assistance Order" acceptable terminology in the context of a furniture business app?

Tags: terminology, desktop-application

The software I work on is used in furniture designing, manufacturing and selling. It is used by designers, factories and stores. We are building a feature where i.e.:

- A store received a broken piece that is part of the design and they want the factory to send this specific piece again;
- A factory can request a new adjustment to the designer because there were some differences in the materials;

In a nutshell, it indicates that something needs to be done, and the user can select a specific section of the design that needs this "something". It is similar to a Technical Assistance but not exactly.

All of this is done opening a new [thing that we're trying to name]. The first name thought were "Assistance Order", but it sounded odd to some of us. So we tried thinking a little more, and then "Assistance Request", "Help Request", "Ask for help" were other suggestions.

Are any of these suggestions applicable to the meaning we're trying to convey? Is there a better way to call this?

Answer (score 1):

"Assistance Order" is a bit of a vague term. I have not see any other companies using this term and I do not think people would understand what it means right away.

You best bet is to use something that everyone is familiar with. If I ordered something on website and something went wrong I would immediately look for a button that says "report a problem", "request help", "is there a problem with your order", etc. Use something that is industry standard, that way people will recognize it immediately.

Hope this helps